# totally multiplicative function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Let $f$ be a totally multiplicative function, $f(n+N)=f(n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $|f(n)|=1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $gcd(n,N)=1$

My approach is to prime factorise $n+N=\prod_{i} p_i^{a_i}$, then $f(n+N)=f(p_{1}^{a_{1}})...f(p_{n}^{a_{n}})$

We also prime factorise $n=\prod_i p_i^{b_i}$, then $f(n)=f(q_1^{b_{1}})...f(q_n^{b_{n}})$

$f(p_1^{a_{1}})...f(p_n^{a_{n}})=f(q_1^{b_{1}})...f(q_n^{b_{n}})$ Since $gcd(n,N)=1$, implies that $gcd(n,n+N)=1$. However as the primes on left are different than the right, the only possible case where the two are equal is when all the exponents $a_i,b_i=0$. Thus $f(n)=1$.

However, not sure where does the absolute value comes in. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: yes, that is what was thinking along, wait how does imply 1 or 0 ? @lulu

Comment: Ok...so does that answer your question?

Comment: Im sorry, but I don't understand why does it imply 1 or 0 ? could you explain ?

Comment: So we need to instead find a wait to reject 0 ?

Comment: Well, Im being honest here, that's really the question

Comment: So something like, since $f(1)=1$, we have $f(1+N)=f(1)=1$, so $f(n)=1, \forall n$ right ?

Comment: okay, so Im just legit copying the question straight, here it is Let $f : N \rightarrow C$ be a totally multiplicative function which is also 
periodic of period $N$ (i.e. , $n＋ N = n$） for every N). Prove that 
$|f(n)| = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $gcd(n,N) = 1$

Comment: okay no problem, sorry about the ambiguity, I apologise

Comment: Ah, I think I was misreading.  Is it your understanding that $N$ is a fixed value here?

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comments since I now believe the assumption is requiring $N$ to be a fixed natural number.  In that case, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916743/completely-multiplicative-and-periodic-function)